# Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle : How is particle position determined more accurately with shorter wavelengths?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In this principle, how can shorter wavelengths on the particle leads to determine more accurate position of the particle?
I think it is somewhere related to reflection of the light from the particle, but I can't understand it completely. Please reply.

Comment: Note that this idea is not the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.

Comment: More accurately, it is the wavelength relative to the size of the object that is significant in scattering.

Answer (score 0):

Given a piece of matter (*particle*) of a fixed size the longer the wavelength is the less scattering the wave suffers when it hits the particle. That means that the wave may just pass on without noticing the "thing". This is the reason for the blue color of the sky. Remember what happens to sound: the high frequency waves will reflect/diffract happily in all directions where you can measure and infer something about the object when hitting it but the low frequency sound just passes by, so no information can be had about it.

Comment: I think OP wants to know why longer wavelengths scatter less.